# @OrderBy causing org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to parse order-by fragment

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa

I added a @OrderBy on my project and now i'm getting the following error:

```
17:10:35,125 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."blueMonster.war#blueMonster": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."blueMonster.war#blueMonster": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: blueMonster] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: blueMonster] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1239) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:855) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44) [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:253) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createCollectionPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:201) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:430) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to parse order-by fragment
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.OrderByFragmentTranslator.translate(OrderByFragmentTranslator.java:69) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.Template.translateOrderBy(Template.java:728) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.<init>(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:578) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister.<init>(OneToManyPersister.java:89) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor32.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:231) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: antlr.CommonToken cannot be cast to antlr.Token
    at antlr.CharScanner.makeToken(CharScanner.java:173) [antlr-2.7.7.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByLexer.mIDENT(GeneratedOrderByLexer.java:239) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByLexer.nextToken(GeneratedOrderByLexer.java:139) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at antlr.TokenBuffer.fill(TokenBuffer.java:69) [antlr-2.7.7.jar:]
    at antlr.TokenBuffer.LA(TokenBuffer.java:80) [antlr-2.7.7.jar:]
    at antlr.LLkParser.LA(LLkParser.java:52) [antlr-2.7.7.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.expression(GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.java:565) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.sortKey(GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.java:346) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.sortSpecification(GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.java:241) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.orderByFragment(GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.java:190) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.OrderByFragmentTranslator.translate(OrderByFragmentTranslator.java:63) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    ... 24 more
```

If i remove the @OrderBy it runs fine.

After some digging i found out a workaround, but i cannot use it, the workaround is to change the pom.xml and on the hibernate-core dependency add an exclusion to antl

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>

       <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
             <groupId>antlr</groupId>
             <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I'm using JPA so i don't have the hibernate-core on my pom.xml
My dependencias on pom.xml are:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.auth.message</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaspi-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.jacc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jacc-api_1.5_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.rmi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.resource</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.management.j2ee</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-MR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsp-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketbox</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.21.Final</version>

            <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>picketbox-spi-bare</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbosssx-bare</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-logging-spi</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
      <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>


        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketbox-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketbox-infinispan</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.21.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-controller-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-dmr</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>async-http-servlet-3.0</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>

             <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>


        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.byteslounge</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-properties</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>deltaspike-core-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>deltaspike-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I'm using Wildfly, how can i solve this issue?

After reading @Guillermo Fernández reply i did the following:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=antlr
```

The outcome was:

```
[INFO] blueMonster:blueMonster:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.hibernate:hibernate-infinispan:jar:4.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    \- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO]       \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
```

Following his steps i also updated my pom.xml, but something else is also cause the error, since its happening, how do i identify with ones do i have to exclude?

My @OrderBy

```
@OrderBy("data") 
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "csr")
    private List<CsrSeveridadeLog> severidadeLogList;
```

Comment: If you have an error about `@OrderBy` annotation then please paste code that declares it and code that throws an exception.

Comment: The code on that is pretty simple and straigthforward, i'll update the question.
The exception is throw when i launch the server.

Comment: JBoss probably includes hibernate. Try to use `<scope>provided</scope>` on hibernate dependency in pom.xml

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi my problem is on wich of the dependecies i should place the <scope>provided</scope>, since i'm using jpa there is no hibernate-core to set this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After several attempts with exclusions, I solved adding

```
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
```

to JAVA_OPTS in JBoss launching script as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266655/orderby-causes-java-lang-classcastexception-antlr-commontoken-cannot-be-cast-t).

Answer (score 7):

First at all, about the workaround, take into account that the hibernate-core version you are using is 4.3 (as you can see in the error's stacktrace) not the 4.0.1.

In the simplest scenario, the workaround means that your app includes an antlr's jar. By default, the module *org.hibernate* that Wildfly AS loads cause the loading of the *org.antlr* module's jars. The explicit dependecy doesn't appear in your pom so maybe it is implicit referenced by another dependecy or the jar is already in the app's project and then packaged within.

I think you should review and fix the dependencies and/or clean the jars archives but if you really can't do it I suggest you to try to exclude the antlr module using the corresponding deployment descriptor that you will must package into your app.
Sorry I don't have any example of descriptor to show you right now. Read [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules.html#sect-Introduction-1) and [this doc](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Class+Loading+in+AS7) to know how to write it and to learn about classloading and Jboss AS modules dependencies. Don't worry about the AS version referenced in these links, respect of this issue applies pretty much the same.

**Improve:**
To find out which dependency includes antlr you can use [maven dependecy plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html). I run this command line on your list of dependecies:

> mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=antlr

The output is:

```
[INFO] \- org.hibernate:hibernate-infinispan:jar:4.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    \- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO]       \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
```

I am guessing but you are packaging your web application within the dependencies you list, because there is not parent pom or referenced bom that set scope other than *compile*. In that case it is really a mess, I suggest to you to use Wildfly BOMs to resolve the version of the dependencies that you app needs (read about [here](https://github.com/wildfly/boms) and [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/maven-tutorials/jboss-maven/using-wildfly-boms) to know how to use/add it) and begin for setting scope *provided* to all dependencies that Wildfly provides (so they are listed in the BOM).
Next, maybe you need to declare explicit reference to some Wildfly's module to include the jars/dependencies in your classpath's app that aren't includes automatically or by default, but I thinks it is for another question.

About the workaround, in your case you should add something like this (according to the [pom of Wildfly project](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/8.2.0.Final/pom.xml)) to exclude the antlr jar, and probably something else is missing too.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>picketbox-infinispan</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.21.Final</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>picketbox-spi-bare</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbosssx-bare</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-logging-spi</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
      <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, the workaround is just a copy paste from the example i found.
From what i understand i would need to find what is using the antl and then use the exclusion of antl from it, so the cotainer would use it w/o this problem, right?

I then proceed to try removing antl from my maven repository and see what happens, the error did not show up( of course i can't update maven since it would re-download the antl.jar ) but then my omnifaces stoped working, i tryed to add the exclusion to antlr on omnifaces, but it had no effect, and once maven updated the project antlr was redowloaded.

Comment: I edit the answer, take a look. From your comment I realise that you have poor knowledgement about maven. Don't be afraid, for a basic use It is really simple and useful to resolve project libraries dependencies, [http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/] (here is a good book about maven).

Comment: Thanks again for helping @Guillermo, i did some of the steps you helped, how to i identify the dependecys that i need to exclude and from wich one?The ones you said we're on my pom.xml but the error still persist, like you said something else is probably missing.
Sorry i really don't understand maven fully, been using it just to easy my managment on dependecies.

Comment: On a side note, is there any way for me to force a version of antlr to be used? Doing more research i found out that on version 3.0+ it wouldn't cause this error, maybe trying to force this version to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue while deploying the web application in JBOSS EAP 6 and fixed it adding [antr](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/antlr/antlr/2.7.7) dependency with the **`provided`** scope at the root level.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>antlr</groupId>
   <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```